# Segmentation Fault using MPI_Sendrecv with a 2D contiguous array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, mpi

my problem is quite simple. When using MPI_Sendrecv, its generates systematically a segfault. I had the same problem earlier with the use of 2D array and a basic MPI_Send but finally solved it. As I tried the same solution that work in the last case, this did not change anything. Thus I'm asking help !

So basically, I allocate all my matrix by this code :

```
    double**
    allocateMatrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        double **M; // Row pointer
        double *Mdata; // Where data will be actually storde

        M = calloc(rows, sizeof *M);
        Mdata = calloc(rows*cols, sizeof(double));

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) 
            M[i] = Mdata+ i*rows;

        return M;
    }
```

I did it because I read that MPI_Sendrecv should not work with non contiguous data...

Here is where I get my error:

```
    double **submtx;
    submtx = allocateMatrix(submtx_dim, submtx_dim);

    /* 
    ...
    */

    MPI_Sendrecv(&(submtx[0][0]), 1, left_col, neighbours[0], LEFT_COL,
                 &tmp_rcol, SUB_MTX_SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE, neighbours[0], RIGHT_COL,
                 my_grid, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

I know for having it tested that the error is from the syntax of the first argument given to MPI_Sendrecv. I use MPI subarray and a grid plus a shift to get my neighbours on the grid, but this code has been already working with a basic version using Send/Recv separately. The only change in it has been the replacement of Send/recv calls by MPI_Sendrecv calls in order to simplify the code ... so I don't think the whole code should be necessary.

Any ideas ?

I tried :

```
    MPI_Sendrecv(&submtx, ...
    MPI_Sendrecv(submtx, ...
```

None of it worked and I still get a segmentation fault at this line.

Comment: `M = calloc(rows, sizeof *M);` (but pointers and double could have equal sizes on your particular platform.

Comment: Oh fudge yes indeed... well it did not change anything because they have equal sizes but this is a fairly big mistake anyway so thanks =)

Comment: The form in my answer is less error prone. (since *M gets the sizeof info right from the intended object) It works for any type.

Comment: Yes you're right, that's what I wanted to say in my comment above, even if it works in this case, it's a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I got rid of my segmentation fault. The syntax written in my question was actually good, &(submtx[0][0]) was not the problem... also as pointed out in this post, submtx[0] is also working ([MPI_Type_create_subarray and MPI_Send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583540/mpi-type-create-subarray-and-mpi-send)).

This is actually a bit tricky, because there is no real problem at all except that I have to do some stupid stuff before the real one :

not working code:

```
    MPI_Barrier(my_grid);

    do {

        MPI_Sendrecv(&(submtx[0][0], ...)

        /*
        ...
        */

    } while (cond);
```

and working code:

```
    MPI_Barrier(my_grid);

    double *stupid_allocation;
    stupid_allocation = calloc(submtx_dim*submtx_dim, sizeof(double));

    do {

        MPI_Sendrecv(&(submtx[0][0]), ...)

        /*
        ...
        */

    } while (cond);
```

While I'm happy my problem is finally fixed, I would really like to get an answer to the problem anyway, meaning "why does it not work when removing an allocation (or anything else I presume) that won't be of any use ??

Comment: That sort of behaviour is almost always a sign of a buffer overflow somewhere. Time to break out a tool like valgrind and see what is going wrong.

Comment: There is no obvious solution, I checked the debug file produce by a memcheck with valgrind and there is no occurrences of both "after" and "before" words in it, thus I don't think it is a buffer overflow. But I am definitely not a valgrind warrior so I'm still heading that way anyway...

Comment: Valgrind is still giving to me a lot of error, but it seems that all of them are due to MPI_Init using uninitialized values and from the freeing of my specific datatypes (created by MPI_Type_create_subarray) which seems to be also uninitialized when freeing (I did commit them though)...

Answer (score 0):

MPI_Sendrecv expects a pointer to a buffer of data as first parameter (void *)

http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Sendrecv.html

so, try this

```
double* // pointer to double (not pointer to pointer)
    allocateMatrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        return calloc(rows * cols, sizeof(double));
    }
```

then later

```
double *submtx;
submtx = allocateMatrix(submtx_dim, submtx_dim);

/* 
...
*/

MPI_Sendrecv(submtx,....
```

I suppose the commented area writes something into the matrix...

To access the value in the row **r** and column **c** do this

```
smbmtx[c + r * submtx_dim] = 1.234;
```

Comment: My actual function allocates one contiguous block of memory and returns a pointer of pointer to access it in a 2D way, in order to simplify such process. Modifying it to return a double pointer is not the answer I'm looking for... while it could fix the problem, its also asking me to change nearly all my code to fit on specific problem that may be fixed in another way.

As I understand this syntax "&(submtx[0][0])", it's currently returning the address to the start of this one contiguous matrix I allocated, the same way it would have be done by using "submtx" with your solution, right ?