# Memory corruption with fortran90 deallocate statement

Tags: memory, fortran, mpi

I've built a minimal example of distributing fortran derived types using `MPI_PACK`, `MPI_SEND`, `MPI_RECV`, and also exchanging their boundaries to test `MPI_SENDRECV` for `MPI_PACKED` derived types.

The code just works fine, but it shows some strange behavior that I attribute to some memory corruption if I put `deallocate` statement in the middle of the code, while the code works fine with the `deallocate` statement at the end of the code. The `dellocate` statements are marked with `(*)` at the left side of the `main` script.

The flow of the code is,

1) `MPI_PACK` the whole derived type.

2) Distribute with `MPI_SEND`, `MPI_RECV`, and `MPI_UNPACK` recovering the derived type 
structure.

3) `MPI_PACK` the boundaries of the distributed local derived type.

4) Exchange boundaries between adjacent processors using `MPI_SENDRECV`

I've put the exactly same code that I tested, so they would compile well with like `mpif90 mod_data_structure.f90 main.f90 -o main`, and the problem would be totally reproducible. The results below are the output from `mpirun -np 2 main`.

```
module mod_data_structure
  implicit none

  type type_cell
    real(selected_real_kind(15,307)):: xc(2)
    real(selected_real_kind(15,307)):: values_c(8)
    integer                      :: flag_boundary
  end type type_cell

  type type_cell_list
    type(type_cell)              :: cell(13,13)
  end type type_cell_list

  type type_cell_list_local
    type(type_cell),allocatable  :: cell(:,:)
  end type type_cell_list_local

end module mod_data_structure
```

```
program main
  use MPI
  use mod_data_structure
  implicit none

  integer,parameter          :: nxmax = 9, nymax = 9, nbc = 2
  integer                    :: i, j, k, ii, jj
  type(type_cell_list)       :: A
  type(type_cell_list_local) :: A_local
  type(type_cell)            :: acell
  character(len=20)          :: write_fmt

  ! MPI variables
  integer                    :: n_proc, my_id, ierr, source, dest
  integer                    :: tag, tag_send, tag_recv
  integer                    :: status ( MPI_STATUS_SIZE ), &
                                status_l ( MPI_STATUS_SIZE ), &
                                status_r ( MPI_STATUS_SIZE )
  integer,allocatable        :: local_size(:), local_start(:)
  real(selected_real_kind(15,307)):: tmp
  character,allocatable      :: buffer(:), buffer_l(:), buffer_lg(:), buffer_r(:), buffer_rg(:) 
  integer                    :: bufsize, bufsize_gc
  integer                    :: left_proc, right_proc
  integer                    :: DBL_SIZE, INT_SIZE, position_local
  integer                    :: position_l, position_r
  integer,allocatable        :: position(:)

  call MPI_INIT ( ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_RANK ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id,  ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, n_proc, ierr )

  call MPI_PACK_SIZE(1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_COMM_WORLD,DBL_SIZE,ierr)
  call MPI_PACK_SIZE(1,MPI_INTEGER         ,MPI_COMM_WORLD,INT_SIZE,ierr)

  ! Construct the derived data types
  if ( my_id .eq. 0 ) then

    do i = 1,nxmax+2*nbc
      do j = 1,nymax+2*nbc
        A%cell(i,j)%flag_boundary = 0
        do k =  1,8
          A%cell(i,j)%values_c(k) = 0.d0
        enddo
        do k = 1,2
          A%cell(i,j)%xc(k) = 0.d0
        enddo
      enddo
    enddo

    do i = 1+nbc,nxmax+nbc
      do j = 1+nbc,nymax+nbc
        ii = i - nbc
        jj = j - nbc
        A%cell(i,j)%flag_boundary = 10*ii + jj
        do k = 1,8
          A%cell(i,j)%values_c(k) = 1.d1*ii + jj + 0.1d0*k
        enddo
        do k = 1,2
          A%cell(i,j)%xc(k) = 1.d1*ii + jj + 0.1d0*k
        enddo
      enddo
    enddo

    write(write_fmt, '(a,i,a)') '(',nymax+2*nbc,'i3)'
    write(*,*) 'my_id ', my_id
    write(*,*) 'Total flag_boundary'
    do i = 1,nxmax+2*nbc
      write(*,write_fmt) A%cell(i,:)%flag_boundary
    enddo
    write(*,*) ' '

  endif

  !*** Test MPI_PACK and MPI_SEND / MPI_RECV
  ! Prepare for the distribution
  allocate ( local_size(n_proc), local_start(n_proc), position(n_proc) )
  local_size  = 0
  local_start = 1

  tmp  = (nymax+2*nbc) / n_proc
  ! 'local_size'
  do i = 1,n_proc-1
    local_size(i) = ceiling(tmp)
  enddo
  local_size(n_proc) = nymax + 2*nbc - (n_proc - 1)*ceiling(tmp)

  allocate ( A_local%cell(nxmax+2*nbc,local_size(my_id+1)) )  ! ###

  ! 'local_start'
  do i = 1,n_proc-1
    local_start(i+1:n_proc) = local_start(i+1:n_proc) + local_size(i)
  enddo

  ! allocate 'buffer'
  bufsize = maxval(local_size) * ( nxmax + 2*nbc ) * ( (8+2)*DBL_SIZE + (1)*INT_SIZE )
  allocate ( buffer(bufsize) )

  position = 0
  if ( my_id .eq. 0 ) then

    ! Assign 'A_local' for 'my_id .eq. 0' itself
    do j = 1, local_size(my_id+1)
      do i = 1, nxmax+2*nbc
        A_local%cell(i,j) = A%cell(i,j)
      enddo
    enddo

    do k = 2, n_proc ! w/o 'my_id .eq. 0' itself
      do j = local_start(k), local_start(k) + local_size(k) - 1
        do i = 1,nxmax+2*nbc
          acell = A%cell(i,j)
          call MPI_PACK(acell%xc,            2, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, buffer, bufsize, position(k), MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
          call MPI_PACK(acell%values_c,      8, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, buffer, bufsize, position(k), MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
          call MPI_PACK(acell%flag_boundary, 1, MPI_INTEGER         , buffer, bufsize, position(k), MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        enddo
      enddo

      dest = k-1 ! ###
      tag  = k-1
      call MPI_SEND (buffer, bufsize, MPI_PACKED, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr )

    enddo

  else ! ( my_id .ne. 0 ) then

    source = 0
    tag    = my_id
    call MPI_RECV (buffer, bufsize, MPI_PACKED, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr )

    position_local = 0
    do j = 1, local_size(my_id+1)
      do i = 1, nxmax+2*nbc
        call MPI_UNPACK (buffer, bufsize, position_local, acell%xc,            2, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        call MPI_UNPACK (buffer, bufsize, position_local, acell%values_c,      8, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        call MPI_UNPACK (buffer, bufsize, position_local, acell%flag_boundary, 1, MPI_INTEGER         , MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

        A_local%cell(i,j) = acell 
      enddo
    enddo

  endif

(*)!deallocate ( buffer ) 

  do k = 1,n_proc
    if ( my_id .eq. (k-1) ) then
      write(write_fmt, '(a,i,a)') '(',local_size(my_id+1),'i3)'
      write(*,*) ' Before MPI_SENDRECV'
      write(*,*) 'my_id ', my_id
      write(*,*) 'cols  ', local_size(my_id+1)
      do i = 1,nxmax+2*nbc
        write(*,write_fmt) A_local%cell(i,:)%flag_boundary
      enddo
      write(*,*) ' '
    endif
    !call MPI_BARRIER ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr )    
  enddo

  ! Test MPI_SENDRECV 
  bufsize_gc = nbc * ( nxmax + 2*nbc ) * ( (8+2)*DBL_SIZE + (1)*INT_SIZE )
  allocate ( buffer_l(bufsize_gc), buffer_lg(bufsize_gc), buffer_r(bufsize_gc), buffer_rg(bufsize_gc) )

  ! 'left_proc'
  if ( my_id .eq. 0 ) then
    left_proc = MPI_PROC_NULL
  else ! ( my_id .ne. 0 ) then
    left_proc = my_id - 1
  endif

  ! 'right_proc'
  if ( my_id .eq. n_proc-1 ) then
    right_proc = MPI_PROC_NULL
  else ! ( my_id .ne. n_proc - 1 )
    right_proc = my_id + 1
  endif

  ! pack 'buffer_l' & 'buffer_r'
  position_l = 0
  do j = 1,nbc
    do i = 1,nxmax+2*nbc
      acell = A_local%cell(i,j)
      call MPI_PACK(acell%xc,            2, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, buffer_l, bufsize_gc, position_l, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      call MPI_PACK(acell%values_c,      8, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, buffer_l, bufsize_gc, position_l, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      call MPI_PACK(acell%flag_boundary, 1, MPI_INTEGER         , buffer_l, bufsize_gc, position_l, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    enddo
  enddo

  position_r = 0
  do j = local_size(my_id+1)-nbc+1, local_size(my_id+1)-nbc+nbc
    do i = 1,nxmax+2*nbc
      acell = A_local%cell(i,j)
      call MPI_PACK(acell%xc,            2, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, buffer_r, bufsize_gc, position_r, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      call MPI_PACK(acell%values_c,      8, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, buffer_r, bufsize_gc, position_r, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      call MPI_PACK(acell%flag_boundary, 1, MPI_INTEGER         , buffer_r, bufsize_gc, position_r, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    enddo
  enddo

  tag_send = my_id
  tag_recv = right_proc
  call MPI_SENDRECV (buffer_l,  bufsize_gc, MPI_PACKED, left_proc,  0, &
                     buffer_rg, bufsize_gc, MPI_PACKED, right_proc, 0, &
                     MPI_COMM_WORLD, status_l, ierr )

  tag_send = my_id
  tag_recv = left_proc
  call MPI_SENDRECV (buffer_r,  bufsize_gc, MPI_PACKED, right_proc,  0, &
                     buffer_lg, bufsize_gc, MPI_PACKED, left_proc,   0, &
                     MPI_COMM_WORLD, status_r, ierr )

  ! fill left boundary
  position_l = 0 
  do j = 1,nbc
    do i = 1,nxmax+2*nbc
      call MPI_UNPACK (buffer_lg, bufsize_gc , position_l, acell%xc,            2, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      call MPI_UNPACK (buffer_lg, bufsize_gc , position_l, acell%values_c,      8, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      call MPI_UNPACK (buffer_lg, bufsize_gc , position_l, acell%flag_boundary, 1, MPI_INTEGER         , MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

      A_local%cell(i,j) = acell
    enddo
  enddo

  ! fill right boundary
  position_r = 0
  do j = local_size(my_id+1)-nbc+1, local_size(my_id+1)-nbc+nbc
    do i = 1,nxmax+2*nbc
      call MPI_UNPACK (buffer_rg, bufsize_gc , position_r, acell%xc,            2, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      call MPI_UNPACK (buffer_rg, bufsize_gc , position_r, acell%values_c,      8, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      call MPI_UNPACK (buffer_rg, bufsize_gc , position_r, acell%flag_boundary, 1, MPI_INTEGER         , MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

      A_local%cell(i,j) = acell
    enddo
  enddo

  do k = 1,n_proc
    if ( my_id .eq. (k-1) ) then
      write(write_fmt, '(a,i,a)') '(',local_size(my_id+1),'i3)'
      write(*,*) ' After MPI_SENDRECV'
      write(*,*) 'my_id ', my_id
      write(*,*) 'cols  ', local_size(my_id+1)
      do i = 1,nxmax+2*nbc
        write(*,write_fmt) A_local%cell(i,:)%flag_boundary
      enddo
      write(*,*) ' '
    endif
    !call MPI_BARRIER ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr )    
  enddo

(*)deallocate ( buffer )
  deallocate ( buffer_l, buffer_lg, buffer_r, buffer_rg )

  call MPI_FINALIZE ( ierr )

end program
```

With `deallocate(buffer)` in the middle of the code, a part of the output looks like below, which worked as I intended.

```
  After MPI_SENDRECV
 my_id            0
 cols             6
  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0 11 12 15 16
  0  0 21 22 25 26
  0  0 31 32 35 36
  0  0 41 42 45 46
  0  0 51 52 55 56
  0  0 61 62 65 66
  0  0 71 72 75 76
  0  0 81 82 85 86
  0  0 91 92 95 96
  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

But if I locate `deallocate(buffer)` in the middle of the code, the same part of the output looks like this.

```
  After MPI_SENDRECV
 my_id            0
 cols             6
  0  0  0  0  0  0
******  0  0  0  0
****** 11 12 15 16
****** 21 22 25 26
****** 31 32 35 36
****** 41 42 45 46
****** 51 52 55 56
****** 61 62 65 66
****** 71 72 75 76
****** 81 82 85 86
  0  0 91 92 95 96
  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

And if I change `write` format to show more digits of integer, they are 10 digits of integer which goes like `1079533568`.

I've seen this kind of problem at [Segmentation Fault using MPI_Sendrecv with a 2D contiguous array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129297/segmentation-fault-using-mpi-sendrecv-with-a-2d-contiguous-array), but there were no clear answer to the reason why putting the `deallocate` statement of variables that I wouldn't use for the rest of the code at the middle of the code makes such problem.

Where this problem stems from?

Comment: Your code won't compile - (a,i,a) is an invalid format, you need to provide a width on the integer part

Comment: @IanBush I'm using ifort 19.0.5.281, and with this compiler the code compiles fine. I suppose the compiler took care of the invalid format. Thank you for letting me know that is an invalid format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I'm answering this question fairly, but my practical experience with derived types is that the safest way to handle them with different MPI implementations is to not use any advanced MPI constructs and keep all derived type work on the Fortran side.

For example, I would write `pure` functions to pack and expand your datatypes:

```
integer, parameter :: TYPE_CELL_BUFSIZE = 11

pure function type_cell_pack(this) result(buffer)
   class(type_cell), intent(in) :: this
   real(real64) :: buffer(TYPE_CELL_BUFSIZE)

   buffer(1:8) = this%values_c
   buffer(9:10) = this%xc

   ! It will be faster to not use a separate MPI command for this only
   buffer(11) = real(this%flag_boundary,real64)

end function type_cell_pack

pure type(type_cell) function type_cell_unpack(buffer) result(this)
   real(real64), intent(in) :: buffer(TYPE_CELL_BUFSIZE)

   this%values_c = buffer(1:8)
   this%xc = buffer(9:10)
   this%flag_boundary = nint(buffer(11))

end function type_cell_unpack
```

And then write two wrappers for MPI comms using MPI_send and MPI_recv only, like this for a scalar quantity:

```
subroutine type_cell_send_scalar(this,fromCpu,toCpu,mpiWorld)
   type(type_cell), intent(inout) :: this
   integer, intent(in) :: fromCpu,toCpu,mpiWorld

   real(real64) :: mpibuf(TYPE_CELL_BUFSIZE)

   if (cpuid==fromCpu) then 
      mpibuf = type_cell_pack(this)
      call mpi_send(...,mpibuf,...,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,...)
   elseif (cpuid==toCpu) then 
      call mpi_recv(...,mpibuf,...,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,...)
      this = type_cell_unpack(mpibuf)
   endif

end subroutine type_cell_send_scalar
```

And the following for an array quantity:

```
subroutine type_cell_send_array(these,fromCpu,toCpu,mpiWorld)
   type(type_cell), intent(inout) :: these(:)
   integer, intent(in) :: fromCpu,toCpu,mpiWorld

   integer :: i,ncell,bufsize
   real(real64) :: mpibuf(TYPE_CELL_BUFSIZE*size(these))

   ncell = size(these)
   bufsize = ncell*TYPE_CELL_BUFSIZE

   if (cpuid==fromCpu) then 
      do i=1,ncell
        mpibuf((i-1)*TYPE_CELL_BUFSIZE+1:i*TYPE_CELL_BUFSIZE) = type_cell_pack(these(i))
      end do

      call mpi_send(bufsize,mpibuf,...,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,...)
   elseif (cpuid==toCpu) then 
      call mpi_recv(bufsize,mpibuf,...,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,...)
      do i=1,ncell
        these(i) = type_cell_unpack(mpibuf((i-1)*TYPE_CELL_BUFSIZE+1:i*TYPE_CELL_BUFSIZE))
      end do
   endif

end subroutine type_cell_send_array
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer with such a detailed example code. It seems to help me a lot with the real implementation of MPI routines to my code. Thank you :)